# Erroneous space after using getline()

Tags: c++, arrays, getline

I'm writing a program to take user input and write it into a series of parallel arrays. I've already got the code written and it compiles and does what it needs to, but I've been doing some bugfixing and realized that some of my output was wonky.

My input is:

```
ABC 123
Fall 2015
ABC 123

BAC 213
Fall 2015
BAC 213

CAB 321
Fall 2015
CAB 321
```

However, what I'm getting back is:

```
ABC 123
Fall 2015
ABC 123


BAC 213
Fall 2015

CAB 321
Fall 2015
CAB 321
```

I think I've isolated the problem bit of code to the following section:

```
for ( ; loopnum < clnum; loopnum++) {
                cout << "What was the name of the class?:\n";
                cin.ignore();
                getline(cin, clnam[loopnum]);

                cout << "What about the semester?:\n";
                getline(cin, crsem[loopnum]);

                cout << "Now the course number:\n";
                getline(cin, crnum[loopnum]);

                cout << "And the grade you received:\n";
                cin >> grade[loopnum];
```

I think I read somewhere on here that using getline() can result in erroneous spaces after input, and that seems to be what's happening. Any idea how to resolve this?

**EDIT:**

I actually resolved this problem myself. The issue I was having was completely unrelated to the segment of code I thought was responsible. Rather, I'd been using:

```
getline(infile, clnam[readplace]);
getline(infile, crsem[readplace]);
getline(infile, crnum[readplace]);
```

In a separate function designed to write the array data into a file. Changing those instead into:

```
infile >> clnam[readplace];
infile >> crsem[readplace];
infile >> crnum[readplace];
```

Resolved the issue. I'm not sure why this is the case. That function wasn't even called inside the for loop.

However, this has revealed a new issue. On the first iteration of my loop, the getline call seems to be treated like a cin. By that I mean, entering:

```
ABC 123
Fall 2015
ABC 123
```

Results in:

```
ABC
123
Fall
```

Yet on the second iteration of my loop and beyond, everything works as it ought to.

Comment: We could use a bit more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
cin >> grade[loopnum];
```

the newline at the end of the input is left in the input buffer. So the next iteration when you do call `getline` you get that newline as an empty line, and you go out of phase with the rest of the input.

There are basically two solutions to this:

1. Read the whole line into a string using `getline`, then use some other way to get the integer (e.g. [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol))
2. Read the number as you do now, but then [ignore the rest until a newline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)